# What is the canonical way to check if a function has been called in Python unittest without use of a mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tdd

If I have a class similar to the 1 below and I want to test the various cases for the  bar function, how can I accomplish this without mocking the private functions? In other words, how in Python's unittest library could I achieve something similar to this:

```
def test_bar():
    f = Foo()
    f.bar(3)
    expect(self._is_positive_number).toBeCalled()
```

**foo.py**

```
class Foo():
    def bar(self, x):
       if type(x) is not int:
           print('Please enter a valid integer')
           return False

       if x > 0:
           self._is_positive_number()
       elif x == 0:
           self._is_zero()
       else 
           self._is_negative()

    def _is_positive_number(self):
        print('Positive')
        return True

    def _is_zero(self):
        print('Zero')
        return True

    def _is_negative_number(self):
        print('Negative')
        return True
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, why don't you want to use a mock-based solution?

Comment: In the above case all 3 conditions return True, the only difference is what is printed. However, the print statement is a function of each condition and not of the function bar. Bar's responsibility is to call 1 of these functions, therefore, I believe testing the function bar calls would be the correct way to test bar. I was wondering if there was a way to do this without mocking the other functions. Adding mocks seems like overhead in such a simple case. Would using a mock be the only way to achieve this? If so, would you mind showing an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this without mocking out the private methods. However, the `mock` library (available as `unittest.mock` in the standard library as of 3.3, a separate installation otherwise) makes this relatively painless:

```
try:
    # Python 3.3 or later
    import unittest.mock as mock
except ImportError:
    # Make sure you install it first
    import mock

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.f = Foo()

    def test_bar(self):
        with mock.patch.object(self.f, '_is_positive_number') as is_pos:
            self.f.bar(3)
            self.assertTrue(is_pos.called)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library is a preferred way to go.

Here's a complete example for all three private methods. You can choose shorter names if you prefer, but I'd better stay explicit. Note that, to be safe, you should assert that not only a desired method was called, but that other private methods weren't called:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import Mock


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = Foo()
        self.instance._is_positive_number = Mock()
        self.instance._is_negative_number = Mock()
        self.instance._is_zero = Mock()

    def test_positive(self):
        self.instance.bar(3)
        self.assertTrue(self.instance._is_positive_number.called)
        self.assertFalse(self.instance._is_negative_number.called)
        self.assertFalse(self.instance._is_zero.called)

    def test_negative(self):
        self.instance.bar(-3)
        self.assertFalse(self.instance._is_positive_number.called)
        self.assertTrue(self.instance._is_negative_number.called)
        self.assertFalse(self.instance._is_zero.called)

    def test_zero(self):
        self.instance.bar(0)
        self.assertFalse(self.instance._is_positive_number.called)
        self.assertFalse(self.instance._is_negative_number.called)
        self.assertTrue(self.instance._is_zero.called)
```

Comment: @evkline you are welcome. I've also updated the answer with some more info on the subject.